# HyperSQL partitioned row_number() equivalent

Tags: sql, hsqldb, openoffice.org

I am doing some data conversion with OpenOffice Base (HyperSQL) and would like to generate a `customerID` field based on the first three characters and then three digits to help resolve conflicts.

I have no problem getting the first three characters:

```
CustomerID      Customer_Name
AAA             AAA Services
BUS             Business R US
NOR             Northern Exposure
NOR             North Face
NOR             North Shore Supply
ZEB             Zebra Painting
```

And I would like to get this:

```
CustomerID      Customer_Name
AAA001          AAA Services
BUS001          Business R US
NOR001          Northern Exposure
NOR002          North Face
NOR003          North Shore Supply
ZEB001          Zebra Painting
```

I can see that this would be easily achieved if HyperSQL supported `row_number()`, however it doesn't seem to.

Any other elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1):

HyperSQL 2.2.8 supports [ROWNUM()](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N13FF6). You can use this version as an external database. See this link http://hsqldb.org/web/openoffice.html

With HSQLDB 1.8.0 which is included in OpenOffice, you can do this in multiple steps (after creating the column with the first three characters).

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER SET "CustomerID" = "CustomerID" || '001' 
  WHERE "Customer_Name" IN (
    SELECT MIN("Customer_Name") 
      FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CHAR_LENGTH("CustomerID") = 3
      GROUP BY "CustomerID"
    )
```

Then repeat with '002', '003' etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you asking for is to have a rank per group (in your case the groping is per `CustomerID`). As @fredt said there is no HSQLDB support for `PARTITION BY` (like one have under MSSQL...) but you  can do the following (if adding auto generated **numeric** ID on the top of the string one isn't a biggy)

```
Select ID, CustomerID, Customer_Name,
     (Select 1 + Count(*) From Customers
      Where CustomerID = A.CustomerID
         And Id < A.Id) Rank
 From Customers A
```

The Rank column will give you the row number per gruop

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a ROWNUM() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...) in HSQLDB as well with some limitations. The solution here assumes no duplicates on Customer_Name and no NULL value allowed for Customer_Name.

```
SELECT A.Partition || RIGHT('00' || count(B.Part), 3) AS "CustomerID", Customer_Name
FROM ( SELECT LEFT(Customer_Name,3) AS "Partition", Customer_Name FROM Table ) A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT LEFT(Customer_Name,3) AS "Partition", Customer_Name FROM Table ) B
    ON A.Customer_Name >= B.Customer_Name AND A.Partition = B.Partition
GROUP BY A.Partition, A.Customer_Name
```

Just to make the solution a little more general; when your unique order is on two fields F1, F2 use the expression:

```
ON ( A.F1 = B.F1 AND A.F2 >= B.F2 OR A.F1 > B.F1 ) AND A.Partition = B.Partition
```